# Graph image unusable as PNG in script

Tags: php, string, url

I am trying to get some URL of graph from `Google play`. I parse its html page and get following URL: [this](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lxy&chd=e%3aAACIERGZIiKqMzO7RETMVVXdZmbud3f.iIkQmZohqqsyu7xDzM1U3d5l7u92,fFfs1BwJrRtGu7jWtt4E88tGgTsfzzuUqDo1wwwwsfx-tGyltG2PnAOBOoiv&chds=0.0,1.0&chs=105x75&chma=1,0,1,1&chco=42b6c9ff&chls=2.5,1.0,0.0&chxl=0%3a%7C%7C1%3a%7C%7C2%3a%7C). This link is stored in variable and when I try to display it by `echo`, it is shown correctly (It coincides with URL). But in case if I use this variable to create image by `imagecreatefrompng`, it doesn't work. Although, if I use constant value (The value of very variable which obtained by `echo`) - it works perfectly. So I decided to compare value of variable and constant value and they have difference! There are 245 differences between the two strings.
The first difference between the strings is at position 43 (It's `&` symbol). Why? Seems to me it replaces symbols such as `&` or `%`. How can I avoid this situation?

Comment: urldecode - the link contains urlencoded data

Comment: URL encoding and decoding maybe? for example " " is "%20" inside an url

Comment: `&` = `%26` and so on.

Comment: How to view real URL which is contained in variable? `echo` shows correct URL.

Comment: Maybe fopen wrappers are disabled so fetching remote files is not allowed. Try storing the file locally first before passing it to imagecreatefrompng

Comment: No. When I use constant value like `$var = 'https://www.google......'` - it works great!

Comment: you might want to try the `decodeURIComponent()` function on the variable

Comment: Do you mean `urldecode`? I have tried it already. It returns completely different string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `&` was replaced by `&amp;`! Other symbols were identical. So, the following code solves this problem

```
str_replace("&amp;", "&", $graphDownloads);
```

Hope it helps someone else.